# google actions UnparseableJsonResponse

Tags: json, sdk, action, response, unparseable

I used to solution from this github: https://github.com/OpenDog/actions-on-aws and got it running with the given command "bst proxy lambda index.js"

I am working with Google Actions SDK (not dialogflow or templates).

When I am testing my app in the console simulator (console.actions.google.com) I am getting this error:

```
UnparseableJsonResponse

API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with

'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Root element must be a message.".
```

In the bespoken Dashboard I can see, that the connection is there. And in the response tab of the simulator, I am also seeing what I am getting back. Google responds with "Your test app is not responding at the moment. Try it again later".

Thanks in advance